# How to remove weak reference from iOS project - AFUrlConnectionOperation.m?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking, weak-references

I am using AFNetworking with AFDownloadRequestOperation to do downloads in my iPhone app.
I get an error when building: 
Compile AFUrlConnectionOperation.m
**The current deployment target does not support automated __weak references**

In my code in the file AFUrlConnectionOperation.m this is where i can see the error:

```
- (void)setCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void))block {
    [self.lock lock];
    if (!block) {
        [super setCompletionBlock:nil];
    } else {
        __weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self;
        [super setCompletionBlock:^ {
            __strong __typeof(&*weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

            block();
            [strongSelf setCompletionBlock:nil];
        }];
    }
    [self.lock unlock];
}
```

How can I resolve it and could you please explain me the logic behind this?
Thanks

Comment: AFNetworking requires iOS 5, try to set the deployment target to iOS 5

Comment: Can you please suggest, what can i use on iOS 4?

Comment: for compatibility with iOS 4.3 use the latest 0.10.x release https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/0.10.x